# Grabbing JS object key that is two words

Tags: jquery, json

Does anyone know how i can grab a js object key that is in two words like:

"Category 1":

"Category 2":

I can't seem to get around that space between the two.

Any thoughts would be grand, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean object key?

If you mean an object *property*, then you can access Javascript object properties much like you do with arrays.

```
foo.bar == foo["bar"]
```

.. so you can access "Category 1" using `obj["Category 1"]`.

Comment: it's basically from a JSON object, so I want to take the property value and add it to a p tag in the html...so something like: '.append('<h3>' + data.Category 1 + '</h3>' + '<p>' + data.Category 2 + '</p>')'

Comment: A JSON object **is** a Javascript object (once you parse it and all). You should be able to get this to work: `.append("<h3>" + data["Category 1"] + "</h3>")`.

Parsing a JSON object is another matter. Make sure that you've converted your JSON string to a *real* object by calling `var obj = $.parseJSON(json_string)`, or some equivalent.

Comment: That worked, stupid me had an extra '.' after data. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the array syntax:

`object['Category 1']`

Answer (score 0):

All objects have a key and a value; that being said you can access an objects key that has:
one word  with dot notation === `object.name`

two words with bracket [] notation === `object["Object 1"]`

This can be said that you must write multiword keys with quotation marks, while single words don't need any quotation marks!

CHEERS!